# How can I enter the activity through notification?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications

How can I enter the activity through notification? I recently made a media player activity, when I press the play button a notification pops up and says that the music is playing. I am kind of new to coding and I read the android developers page about this topic and I didn't understand "app's Activity hierarchy" and  how to make the Intent work in my code.

I have a separate activity for every music and it makes its own notification for each one. I need their notification to open their activity not the main or any other. (ex: music1 creates notification1, after getting out of the app if I press notification1 it should get me to music1).

The class:

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Track track, int playButton, int pos, int size) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(context, "tag");

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), track.getImage());

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.diligent_transparent_logo)
                .setContentTitle(track.getTitle())
                .setContentText(track.getText())
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setShowWhen(false)

                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .build();

        notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

Most of my code:

```
 populateTracks();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        createChannel();
    }

 private void createChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CreateNotification.CHANNEL_ID,
                "Diligent", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);

        notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}


private void populateTracks() {
    tracks = new ArrayList<>();

    tracks.add(new Track("You are watching Getting started meditation", "Press here to enter the app", R.drawable.diligent_transparent_logo));
}
```

My manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".meditation.m4" />
```

If there is someone to make me understand how to make this work I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You can use deep links to go to the specific screen of your 
app  [https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link)

Comment: kindly follow the official Doc

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a new Intent to the activity class you want to open, like for example I want to open MainActivity, I will use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
```

And then create the pending Intent which takes context, Request Code in Integer ,
intent and Flags.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this , REQUEST_CODE , intent , 0);
```

Then use this pendingIntent in notification builder like this,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Foreground Service Notification")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_status_splash)
        .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
```